# Openquery where clause using multiple like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run an Openquery with multiple `Where` clause `NOT LIKE` but is giving me the error

> "Error: MALFORMED_QUERY, ERROR at Row:15:Column:16 unexpected token:
>   like".

What I'm trying to run is something like this

```
SELECT  *   from openquery(Server, 'Select Id
        , BodyLength
        , ContentType
        , CreatedById
        , CreatedDate
        , Description
        , IsPrivate
        , LastModifiedById
        , LastModifiedDate
        , Name
        , OwnerId
        , ParentId
        from Attachment
        where LastModifiedDate > 2018-11-16T00:00:00Z
        and (Name NOT like (''SML -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''EARLY -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''DELAYED -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''CLOSED -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''CLOSURE -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''OUTAGE -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''MISC -%'') and
        Name NOT like (''TIME AS A CONTROL%'') and
        Name NOT like (''TEMPORARY -%''))
        order by Id
        LIMIT 10000') x
```

What I want is to exclude all the records that by Name starting like that. 
It runs smoothly when not excluded by name, but I really need it. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say that `2018-11-16T00:00:00Z` is a suspect. Try `CAST(''2018-11-16T00:00:00Z'' as datetime)`. It also should be easy to find the reason by minimizing your query.

Comment: Openquery runs the statement in a linked server. Is this server sql server? What version? Regardless of the details, the query you run must conform to the sql syntax rules of that remote server. So - can you take that query and run it (as is after un-doubling the quotes) in that remote server directly?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the issue is your date constant, not `like`.  It needs delimiters:

```
where LastModifiedDate > ''2018-11-16T00:00:00Z'' and
      (Name NOT like ''SML -%'' and
       Name NOT like (''EARLY -%'') and
       . . .
      )
```

Comment: It did not work, it stops working when I add the like clause, otherwise, the date works perfectly.